# Get scrollpane's child

Tags: flash, scrollpane

I have a ScrollPane component to stage and I give it as source a new MovieClip instance. How can I access the movieclip inside scrollpane?

This is what I have so far but it returns null:

```
var regForm = new RegistrationForm();
regForm.name = "rForm";
regFormSP.source = regForm;
var form = Object(regFormSP.content).getChildByName("rForm");
trace(form) // returns null
```

**UPDATE**

If I list objects I get

```
_level0.regFormSP.instance20.rForm
```

There is an object "instance20" as a parent to rForm...Why is that?

Comment: why can't you carry on using the `regForm` reference?

Comment: yes I could do that but I just to learn why this happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`instance 20` is probably an unnamed container inside the scroll pane that Flash masks and scrolls.  According to the docs, ScrollPane.content is a reference to the display object you assign using ScrollPane.source.  Given that, `regFormSP.content` should be your form, and not child thereof.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/containers/ScrollPane.html#content